# How to unique identify each request in a ASP.NET Core 2 application (for logging)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In a ASP.NET Core 2 application, I need a unique identifier (e.g. Guid) for each request so I can include that id in each log and understand the sequence of logs of each request.

This is not hard to write it myself, but I wonder if there is a builtin feature that I can use or a ASP.NET Core 2 way of achieving this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may use `System.Diagnostics.Activity` class ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/System/Diagnostics/Activity.cs)). From [Activity User Guide](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md#activity-user-guide)

> `Activity.Id` serves as hierarchical Request-Id in terms of [HTTP Correlation Protocol](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/HttpCorrelationProtocol.md)

This is used for example by [Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore) for app monitoring.

Comment: Is there any example how to use it? Activity.Current is null inside controller

Comment: @Giorgi I believe it's the programmer's responsibility to assign a Correlation-Id when the request begins if there isn't a Correlation-Id already present in the incoming request (remember, it's primarily intended for reverse-proxies).

Comment: Hi.  Can you update some of the broken links to this (really good) answer?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're using ApplicationInsights that will automatically populate `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current`, so then you can use `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id` or `.RootId` and can also correlate with your ApplicationInsights logs. (ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/504)

Answer (score 39):

ASP.NET Core also has `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` which uniquely identifies the current request.

It is generated for each incoming request by Kestrel, so isn't suitable for correlating calls to one service from another, but is suitable for correlating logs for a single request together, or to correlating an error message that might be displayed to the user with the corresponding logs.

Comment: From what I understand, it isn't unique, is it? It is sequential and starts at the service start time in ticks, so two requests could have the same id if they come from different instances of the same service.

Comment: @Krzaku It's (now?) unique, using the connection ID and request number.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for a [correlation id](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3201975/application-development/how-to-use-correlation-ids-in-aspnet-web-api.html).  Maybe [Correlation ID Middleware](https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId) would help?

Comment: Is this thread safe? I did a cursory glance at the code, and it looks like the correlation id is stored in context. I think any parallel operations would lose access to this.