# How to track request with serilog in deep calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, interface, serilog

Hello i am  developing a `ASP NET Core application` having an issue with designing interfaces.I am using `serilog` and when a request enters a controller it gets a `GUID` .I am trying to find an elegant way to track individual requests deep in calls without including this `GUID` in all my interfaces.

```
public interface IService
{
   Task GetSomething(string corellationId);  //how do i get rid of this id
}

public interface ISomeOtherService
{
    Task DoSomethingElse(string corellationId); //how do i get rid of this id
}

public class SomeController:Controller
{
   public IService someService {get;set;}

   [HttpGet]
   public Task Get()
   {
     string corellationId=Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     Log.Information($"[{corellationId}] - Request started");
     try
     {
       Log.Information($"[{corellationId}] - Get");
       await this.someService.GetSomething(corellationId);
     }catch(Exception ex)
     {
     Log.Error($"[{corellationId}] - Get",ex.Message);
     }
   }
}

public SomeService:ISomeService
{
   private ISomeOtherService service{get;set;} 
   public GetSomething(corellationId)
   {
       Log.Information("$[{corellationId}] - GetSomething: ");
       this.service.DoSomethingElse(corellationId);
   }
}
```

As you can see if i have some deep calls i would need to change all interfaces so that they all include the `corellationId` which is the `GUID` that was set when the request entered my controller.

Is there any way of tracking individual requests throughout calls without passing this `GUID` from layer to layer?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262812/how-to-unique-identify-each-request-in-a-asp-net-core-2-application-for-logging is of any help?

Comment: The problem is not identifying it.The problem lies in passing it deep into calls which may be in other assemblies etc in order to see in the log where that request stopped (if it failed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `LogContext.PushProperty` - this uses `AsyncLocal` under the hood so **multi-threaded** scenario is no concern.
For more info check this [link](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext)

Answer (score 3):

If you call [*Serilog.AspNetCore*'s `UseSerilog()`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore), and `Enrich.FromLogContext()` on your `LoggerConfiguration`, then ASP.NET Core will assign an (effectively) GUID `RequestId` property for each request, and this will be attached to all events raised during the request automatically, including in deep calls.

Comment: Suppose I have a collection of microservices with a web of relationships. Similar to the OP's question, I would like to generate a correlation id for an entry point service call but re-use the existing if invoking one of my other services. Is it possible to read the RequestId you say is generated from the LogContext for re-use?

Comment: Hi! You're better off using `Activity.Current.TraceId` and `SpanId` for this - those identifiers are intended to flow across service boundaries.