# Serilog - Add custom properties from Request Header to Application Insight Request logs for Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, serilog

I have an Azure Function integrated with Serilog which logs to Application Insights. I have added the custom middleware to log user claims to LogContext. I can see those custom properties in AppInsight Trace logs. But i want to see the same custom properties in Request logs also in Application Insight. Is there a way to attach the custom user claims, so that i can see those in Application InSight Request Events/logs and also in Exception logs.
Kindly advice with some sample.

Comment: Are you using 'UseSerilogRequestLogging' middleware. ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK using **Serilog** we can capture all telemetry information. For all custom telemetry information, we will receive the logs in Trace.

You can use [trackrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackrequest) to add the custom Request information in azure Application Insights.

```cs
 public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>((sp) => 
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                    .CreateLogger();
                return new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true);
            });
        }
```

#### References

- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833441/how-to-track-request-with-serilog-in-deep-calls) thread for adding custom **TraceRequest** created by [Bercovici Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913744/bercovici-adrian).
- [GitHub](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#request-logging) repo of serilog-aspnetcore for adding request logging in Serilog.