# How unique is HttpContext.TraceIdentifier in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, guid

I want to uniquely identify each requests in my asp.net core web api and I'm planning to use `Httpcontext.Traceidentifier` but how can I be sure that no collisions will be made? I mean it's GUID in string but after sending a ton of requests, I noticed that the generated values are similar and according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262812/how-to-unique-identify-each-request-in-a-asp-net-core-2-application-for-logging#comment101033865_52415209), there's a possibility of two requests having the same value. How can I be sure that I can use this as a unique identifier or should I create my own middleware that generates my own unique identifier?

Comment: how do you want to use this unique request id?

Comment: I'll be using it as a correlation id

Comment: It is meant to be used as a correlation id. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/improvements-in-net-core-3-0-for-troubleshooting-and-monitoring-distributed-apps/ and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/observability-asp-net-core-apps/. HttpContext.TraceIdentifier has the same value as Activity.Current.Id.

Comment: The values of HttpContext.TraceIdentifier and Activity.Current.Id are not the same.